# Any API to browse UM MQ queues?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, mq

in a controlled environment where I don't have access to console to browse messages in MQ queues, I would like to have a Java program do it for me (browse and not consume messages). Has someone used any java API before which will browse the MQ messages? Any pointers to this will help.

Comment: I think this is better asked onon softwarerecs. Which MQ product do you mean ?

Comment: I meant IBM MQ queues

Answer (score 1):

[Hermes JMS](https://www.soapui.org/jms/getting-started.html) is a great option, I used it as a separate installation (which I can't find now), however, it comes now embedded with SoapUI

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [amqsbcgc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q023920_.htm?lang=en) program?  That is a sample browse program that ships with MQ and you can run it as a client.

It does have a limited size for the messages it retrieves but the source code is available and could be customized for your own use.

Answer (score 0):

`javax.jms.Session.createBrowser(Queue queue).getEnumeration()` returns an `Enumeration` you can traverse.

Answer (score 0):

[JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/p/jmstoolbox/wiki/Home/) is perfect for dealing with JMS Messages and works very well with WebSphere MQ